# Работа DieHard и NIST sts тестов для проверки рациональных чисел

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Добрый день,

Имеется написанный на c++ генератор псевдослучайных чисел из диапазона (0,1) 
Кто то может быть работал с diehard тестами или же с NIST STS, вопрос в том, работают ли они с рациональными числами или только с натуральными типа int. При преобразовании файла с данными в бинарный вид, выходной файл становится равным 0 байт. С данными типа int все нормально, из чего я сделал вывод что приведенные тесты с double не работают. В документации для себя ответа на этот вопрос не нашел.
Как в таком случае тестировать большой массив случайных чисел из диапазона (0,1) я не нашел.

Comment: Похоже, что да, только для целых чисел. Но разве это проблема? я вижу два варианта решения:

 - домножить все числа на 10 в нужной степени и отбросить дробную часть. При этом можно протестить, вначале домножая на 10, потом на 100, и так далее. Если все последовательности будут случайные, то наверное и исходная также
 - массив, где хранятся вещественные числа, трактовать просто как массив байт и к нему применять алгоритмы.

Comment: Ну основная попытка перевести массив данных в ASCII в бинарный вид с помощью средств DieHard не увенчалась успехом, может быть вы знайте какие нибудь средства которые помогут представить ASCII с вещественными числами в виде бинарника?

Comment: я думаю, что переведя в ascii, Вы ухудшите качество рандома. Если внимательно посмотрите на бинарное представление цифр, поймете.

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатался в своем комментарии, у меня на выходе получается файл формата ASCII с последовательностью данных в виде: 
0.12 0.0053 0.03 и т.д. как мне перегнать такой формат в бинарный да еще что бы его съел diehard или же NIST STS?